# Beginner Q: How to use variables declared in if/else indentation

Tags: python

I've tried everything I can think of at this point. I am trying to create my first game in which the player can make choices by entering one-word answers.

The game works when the questions are isolated. However, if I want to create a decision that redirects the player to another part of the game (Lines 7 to direct to line 10 through river1 variable), I receive the error: NameError: name 'river1' is not defined, even though I defined it in the 7th line.

I assume it is because it is defined within an indentation. However, I don't know how to fix that and still have it work as required. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
print("Welcome to Treasure Island! \nIts your mission to find the treasure.")
crossroads = input("You begin at a cross roads, do you go left or right? ").lower()
if crossroads == "left":
  enemies = input("You ran into enemies, attack? ").lower()
  if enemies == "no":
    print("You ran to the lake")
    river1 = input("You found a long river, it leads somewhere. Swim or wait? ").lower()
  else: 
    print("You were overpowered and died, game over")
if crossroads == "right":
  river1
  if river1 == "swim":
    print("You swam and drowned, Game over")
  else: 
    print("You found a boat")
```

Comment: Defining means to set the variable to a value. If no such setting was executed already the variable is not defined.

Comment: Ari,  I presume there is an error in the program logic. If you go options top to bottom then it is ok however if you go immediatly to right crossword then this is the first time program see variable. You define it again or make function

Answer (score 1):

Explaining the workflow of your program. I tried your program & got this

```
C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\so>python try.py
Welcome to Treasure Island!
Its your mission to find the treasure.
You begin at a cross roads, do you go left or right? left
You ran into enemies, attack? no
You ran to the lake
You found a long river, it leads somewhere. Swim or wait? right
```

---

```
C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\so>python try.py
Welcome to Treasure Island!
Its your mission to find the treasure.
You begin at a cross roads, do you go left or right? right
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 11, in <module>
    river1
NameError: name 'river1' is not defined
```

The reason `river1` is not defined and you getting that error is because when I entered `"right"` the program goes to the **2nd** `if` thus since `crossroads == "left"` will be `False`. When it executes the code on the second `if` there is **REALLY NO variable or object** named `river1`.

Why is there no `river1` variable where you created or put it on the first `if`? Well that is because the first `if` does not even get executed (when I enter "right") thus **NOT** creating your `river1` variable. You might think once you put it there it will be created but it will only be created when that part of code is executed.

So if you would like to have a variable `river1` globally you can create it a top and initialize it let's say `None` or an empty string , your call.

```
river1 = ''

print("Welcome to Treasure Island! \nIts your mission to find the treasure.")
crossroads = input("You begin at a cross roads, do you go left or right? ").lower()
if crossroads == "left":
  enemies = input("You ran into enemies, attack? ").lower()
  if enemies == "no":
    print("You ran to the lake")
    river1 = input("You found a long river, it leads somewhere. Swim or wait? ").lower()
  else: 
    print("You were overpowered and died, game over")
if crossroads == "right":
  river1
  if river1 == "swim":
    print("You swam and drowned, Game over")
  else: 
    print("You found a boat")
```

Answer (score 0):

For variables that may only be defined under certain circumstances, you have a couple of options. First, you can declare them all beforehand:

```
print("Welcome to Treasure Island! \nIts your mission to find the treasure.")
crossroads = input("You begin at a cross roads, do you go left or right? ").lower()
enemies = None
river1 = None
if crossroads == "left":
...
```

Or, you can test to see if they exist:

```
if crossroads == "right":
    if river1 and river1 == "swim":
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is how to reuse your code.
Use functions.

```
def river1_func():
    choice = input("You found a long river, it leads somewhere. Swim or wait? ").lower()
    if choice == "swim":
        print("You swam and drowned, Game over")
    else: 
        print("You found a boat")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Welcome to Treasure Island! \nIts your mission to find the treasure.")
    crossroads = input("You begin at a cross roads, do you go left or right? ").lower()
    if crossroads == "left":
        enemies = input("You ran into enemies, attack? ").lower()
        if enemies == "no":
            print("You ran to the lake")
            river1_func()
        else: 
            print("You were overpowered and died, game over")
    if crossroads == "right":
        river1_func()
```